# React - useState not reflecting the updated values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to bind a value typed by the user, in another input, which is readOnly, but it's reflecting in other input.
Even though the value as I type, it can appear on html, but I'm unable to bind it to other input.
Before I post this question, I already searched the SO to bind values, but most of them bind to html but not other input field, like my case

here is the `codesandbox` code which is causing trouble for me.

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-bose-jr8rr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this with the current implementation of Input.

1. Get `value` as a prop to `Input` and assign to another variable call it `propValue`

```
function Input({
  ...
  ...
  value: propValue
}) {
```

2. Change the `value` property of input as below to fall back to local `value` (value in Input component) if `propValue` is not provided.

```
<input
     ...
     ...
     value={propValue ?? value}
     ...
     ...
 />
```

3. In App.js set the `value` as `employeeId` to the ready only input.

```
<Input
      label="Reflected Id"
      value={employeeId}
      ...
      ...
></Input>
```

[image: Edit laughing-lewin-4t7kv]

Comment: @Lint, check this out !!

Comment: Excellent, working like charm, but may I know the reason what was I doing wrong ?

Comment: The issue was, `Input` was not accepting a prop to show that value directly and it was showing the local value which was defined inside the `Input`.

Answer (score 1):

use setContactForm instead of mutating the state.